# Mysql: find string with most matching starting characters

Tags: mysql, string

I have a problem I would like to know if I can tackle in my mysql query.

I have a list of "names" in my DB:
`id=1, name="name1"`
`id=2, name="name11"`
`id=3, name="name111"`

I would like to get the id of the name in db with the most common characters at the beginning.

=> `name111someignorechar would return 3`

=> `name11someignorechar would return 2`

=> `name1someignorechar would return 1`

Any idea?

If I use the LIKE keyword,
SELECT id FROM names WHERE CONCAT(name,"%") LIKE "name111someignorechar"
It will return me 3 results !

Comment: Are you looking to return 3, 2 and 1 or are you trying to return the content of the name="<something>" i.e. <something> or a different value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select name
from names
where 'name111someignorechar' like concat(name,'%')
order by length(name) desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The current answer does work for the example that the OP has given, but it doesn't really answer the question. The OP asks for a query that orders by the most common characters, but the query only works if the DB entry contains a subset of the characters in the search query, and nothing more.

For example, comparing *name111someignorechar* with *name1otherignorechar* wouldn't work.

There's another solution, as explained here:
http://tech-q-a.tumblr.com/post/58713827644/how-to-sort-results-based-on-the-number-of-identical

We can use a MySQL function that counts the number identical starting-characters for two strings:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS countMatchingBeginChars;
delimiter // 
CREATE FUNCTION `countMatchingBeginChars`( s1 text, s2 text ) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, min_len, j INT; 
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2);

    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN  
      SET min_len = s2_len;  
    ELSE  
      SET min_len = s1_len;  
    END IF; 
    SET j = 0;
     WHILE j <= min_len DO 
        SET j = j + 1;
        IF SUBSTRING(s1,j,1) != SUBSTRING(s2,j,1) THEN
            RETURN j-1;
        END IF;
     END WHILE;
     RETURN min_len;
END//
delimiter ;
```

So,

```
SELECT countMatchingBeginChars("name111someignorechar", "name11")
```

would return 6 (as above), but so would

```
SELECT countMatchingBeginChars("name111someignorechar", "name11otherignore")
```

Now, we can sort the entries in the database according to the number of matching characters:

```
SELECT name FROM names ORDER BY countMatchingBeginChars("name111someignorechar",name) DESC, name
```

If only the entry with the most matching characters is required, we can just return only one result.

```
SELECT name FROM names ORDER BY countMatchingBeginChars("name111someignorechar",name) DESC, name LIMIT 1
```